# How to run master/slave Locust runner programmatically so slaves stops at the end

Tags: python, locust

I have this simple master/slave scripts, using `locustio==0.13.5`. This is the master:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import argparse
import os
import sys
import time

import urllib3

import locust

import utils


class TestSomething(locust.TaskSet):
    @locust.task(1)
    def get_hosts_small(self):
        print(self.locust.message)
        return self.client.get(url='http://localhost', verify=False)

class TheSomething(locust.HttpLocust):
    task_set = TestSomething
    wait_time = locust.constant(0)


urllib3.disable_warnings()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

options = argparse.Namespace()
options.host = "http://localhost"
options.num_clients = 1
options.hatch_rate = options.num_clients
options.num_requests = 10
options.stop_timeout = 1
options.step_load = False
options.reset_stats = False
options.test_duration = 3

options.master_host = 'localhost'
options.master_port = 5557
options.master_bind_host = '*'
options.master_bind_port = 5557
options.heartbeat_liveness = 3
options.heartbeat_interval = 1

options.expect_slaves = 1


test_set = TheSomething
test_set.message = 'Hello'

locust_runner = locust.runners.MasterLocustRunner([test_set], options)
while len(locust_runner.clients.ready) < options.expect_slaves:
    logging.info("Waiting for slaves to be ready, %s of %s connected", len(locust_runner.clients.ready), options.expect_slaves)
    time.sleep(1)

locust_runner.start_hatching(locust_count=options.num_clients, hatch_rate=options.hatch_rate)
time.sleep(options.test_duration)
locust_runner.quit()
locusts.events.quitting.fire(reverse=True)

print(locust_runner.stats)   # actually using custom function to format results
```

and this is the slave:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import argparse
import os
import sys
import time

import locust


class TestSomething(locust.TaskSet):
    @locust.task(1)
    def get_hosts_small(self):
        print(self.locust.message)
        return self.client.get(url='http://localhost', verify=False)

class TheSomething(locust.HttpLocust):
    task_set = TestSomething
    wait_time = locust.constant(0)


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

options = argparse.Namespace()
options.host = "http://localhost"
options.num_clients = 1
options.hatch_rate = options.num_clients
options.num_requests = 10
options.stop_timeout = 1
options.step_load = False
options.reset_stats = False
options.test_duration = 3

options.master_host = 'localhost'
options.master_port = 5557
options.master_bind_host = '*'
options.master_bind_port = 5557
options.heartbeat_liveness = 3
options.heartbeat_interval = 1


test_set = TheSomething
test_set.message = 'Hello'

locust_runner = locust.runners.SlaveLocustRunner([test_set], options)
locust_runner.worker()
```

When I start master and slave, I can see how master waits for a slave to come up, then how slave is executing the test and I see report printed by master before it finished. But slave does not finishes - it hangs running, doing nothing (I assume).

I would like slave to either exit or to restart and attempt to connect to master again in case I just rerun the master script. Does anybody have any idea on how to do that please?

Comment: Hi! What is the reason you are not just using the normal locust --slave and --master command line settings? Are you trying to do something special that is not supported by the runners by default? Running locust programmatically is not really supported in the current version (but will be in 1.0)

Comment: Hello @Cyberwiz. I would like to pass some extra data to the tests - see that `test_set.message = 'Hello'` and it is used later in the tests with `self.locust.message`. Maybe it is not worth it. Also mine initial reason to have bit more control on what is happening (I want to log some of the parameters to the file where I have test results and I also want to post-process the results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just set any parameters as environment variables and read them from the script (os.environ['MY_ENV_VAR'])

If you're running the slaves on the same server that should be easy (just run `export MY_ENV_VAR=Hello` before starting the processes), if you are running slaves on different machines it would be a little more complicated but check out locust-swarm that does the work for you (https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-swarm)

As for the "do stuff after the test" there is a "quitting" event that you can subscribe to:

https://docs.locust.io/en/0.14.5/api.html#available-hooks

Or, for the upcoming 1.0 version:

https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#locust.event.Events.quitting

Comment: Thank you! I need to take a look how to "subscribe" to the event.